# Play background music across all my activities, and stop it only when my app is not displayed

Tags: android

I tried one millions way, but in every way the music keeps playing when i play the HOME button of my mobile.
My last attempt was with application, but i still have the same problem.

This is my code.

```
public class ProvaMusica extends Application {
Intent musica_backGround;
public Background_music musicaDiBackground = new Background_music(); 

    public void avvia(){    
           //this is the class where i manage mediaplayer//////////
           musica_backGround=new Intent(this, Background_music.class); 
           startService(musica_backGround);
    }    


    public void onDestroy(){    
        stopService(musica_backGround);     
    }

}
```

In my first activity i use this code to start the music

```
 ProvaMusica appState = ((ProvaMusica)this.getApplication());
 appState.avvia();
```

Now, what should i do to let the music play when showing other activities and make the music stops when my app is not displayed?

I WANT THE MUSIC TO KEEP PLAYING WHILE MOVING FROM AN ACTIVITY TO ANOTHER, I DON'T WANT TO STOP THE MUSIC AND THEN START IT AGAIN, WHEN A NEW ACTIVITY STARTS.

Comment: have you tried overriding onPause() and stop the music?

Comment: Yes, if i stop the music in onPause() the music stops when i change activity. I want to stop the music only when my app is destroyed or not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i found a way mixing the suggestions all of you gave me.

WITH THIS CODE THE BACKGROUND MUSIC (IN THIS CASE MANAGED WITH A SERVICE) STOPS ONLY WHEN USERS CLOSE THE APP WITH THE BACK BUTTON, WHEN USERS CLOSE THE APP WITH THE HOME BUTTON AND WHEN SCREENS TURN OFF BECAUSE USERS LOCK THE SCREEN WITH THE LOCK BUTTON OF THE DEVICES.

I'd like someone more expert and good at programming than me to confirm this is correct

in this class i check if my current activity is in foreground or not

```
public class GestioneApplicazioneInBackground{
    public static boolean applicazioneInBackground(final Context context) {
          ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) MainActivity.context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
          if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
              return true;
            }
          }

          return false;
        }
}
```

in onStop() and onPause() methods of all my activities i have this code

```
/// if my app and his activities are in background i stop the service i started in my main/first activity////
    if(GestioneApplicazioneInBackground.applicazioneInBackground(this) ){
                      context_of_the_Intent.stopService(intent);    
                  }
                  else{
// if my app and his activities are NOT in background i check if user turned off the screen with the lock button of the device//////        
                    PowerManager kgMgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    boolean showing = kgMgr.isScreenOn();
                    if(!showing){
                         context_of_the_Intent.stopService(intent);     
                    }

                  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is:

1. I have a singleton class that is the SoundManager.
2. On onPause each activity calls soundManager.stopPlayingDelayed. This method starts a timer that will call soundManager.checkIfShouldStop in 1 or 2 seconds. It also saves the lastCloseTime to the current time.
3. Each activity on it's onResume calls soundManager.startPlaying. If already playing the sound manager will ignore the request. This also clears the lastCloseTime
4. In checkIfShouldStop , if the lastCloseTime is not zero and is more than 1 second ago, it means that after the last activity finished, no new activity of my app was started, so the music should be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `Application` class and set it in `AndroidManifest`. in its `onDestroy()` callback, you can use `stopService()` function to stop the service or you can start the service with an `Intent` to stop the music.

Comment: Is `onPause()` will be called first if the activity isn't visible?

Comment: Yes, `onPause()` will be called firstly and then `onDestroy()`

Comment: I edited my post. i tried to use Apllication, but i still have the same problem. Can u take a look?

Comment: Is the music starting after you call the method in the Application class? If so, are you using onDestroy() in the Application class to stop the service with stopService() function?

Comment: Yes, i did.. i think i did! I edited my code again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I have looked again and I saw that Application class does not have onDestroy() method. I tought a little bit what you can do and I come with this idea. In all onDestroy() functions in your activities, sendBroadcast to your service and tell the service wait for a 1sec for example. After 1 sec, stop the music and the service. In all onResume() functions in your all activities again send a broadcast and tell the service not to stop the music.

Comment: Maybe i found a way. IF you are interested you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your app works as a process in the Android operating system. There are various ways for Android OS to terminate processes and sometimes callback functions like onDestroy() may not be called before the process is killed. Therefore if you start and play your music in a service, the music will play as long as your process lives. However, if you want it to stop, when a specific activity of your app is killed, you can override onDestroy() of that activity and broadcast a message for your service to stop the music. *Use a service* to implement this.

Comment: I can't override the method onFinish(). I get this error message
`The method onFinish() of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method`
I look for this error on the internet, but a didn't find a solution.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For Activities, you should override onDestroy() method, I am sorry. onDestroy() method may not be called if the process is being killed, but if the activity is destroyed after navigation to somewhere else, it will be called. If the process is killed by OS or user, your service will inevitably stop no worries about this. I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use this one : Tf you usr media player then Call this method in your activity...

```
MediaPlayer mp=null;

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (!(mp == null)) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
};

v @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!(mp == null)) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
};
```